# Firebase watch (grand) child_added?

Tags: firebase

I have a structure like this...

```
{ addresses:{
     user_mark: {
        1: {postcode: 90210},
        2: {postcode: 10001}
     },
     user_pete: {
        1: {postcode: 90210},
        2: {postcode: 10001}
     },
}
```

Is there a way to watch for any address being added under all users?

Thanks guys.

Comment: See my answer below to get started. To get a better answer, provide some code of what **you** already tried. I also somewhat doubt whether this is your actual data structure, since Firebase would normally turns those user objects (with children `1` and `2`) into an array.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is simply listening for the `value` event:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/addresses');
ref.on(value, function(addresses) {
    addresses.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        var user= userSnapshot.val();
        user.forEach(function(address) {
            console.log(user, address);
        });
    });
});
```

Or something along those lines.

You might want to read the section in the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html), since that explicitly recommends to not build nests.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the help.  I've found the below link, which seems to be what I am looking for.   [Firebase-util](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/tree/master/src/join#keymaps)

Comment: It may be what you are looking for, but Frank's suggestions are what you *should be* looking for and utilizing.

Comment: @Kato: Thanks for the suggestion  I used Firebase.utils a bit and it worked well for some simple data structures.  Coding out the loops ended up being much better. :)